# away3d 3.x vs away3d 4.x

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, away3d

I am new to away3d, and trying to learn this, but the tutorial I found through google explains mainly using away3d 3.x and When I try to run that examples it shows lots of errors(I am using away3d 4.x).

so can any body point me to some good tutorials, which explains about away3d 4.0x concepts.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok fine I got my answer and best sources for examples is this http://away3d.com/images/uploads/releases/away3d-examples-fp11_4_0_9_gold.zip

just download and start doing, it has very good examples

Answer (score 1):

Away3D 4.0 utilizes the new Flash Player 11 MoleHill 3D API.  It is a very low level API that provides console quality 3d graphics acceleration.  Being low level it's a bitch to program.  Enter Away3D 4.0.  Away3D 3.6 utilizes the newer Flash Player 10 3D commands but you won't see the same speed.  3.5 and below target flash player 9 though I suppose any version will work well for a simple application.  If you want high end, use 4.

Comment: Also Packt Press has two offferings you should look into... Away3D 3.6 Essentials and Away3D 3.6 Cookbook.  Friends of Ed has a book The Essential Guide to Away3d 3.5.  Anything on 4 probably hasn't hit the presses yet.

Comment: ha... lol, I could be talking to a ghost, forgot to look at the date. I bet you got your answer by now :)  Anyways hope this helps someone.